# Multiplying Two Cells Returns Zero

Tags: microsoft-excel

I created a formula field that multiplies two cells and it returns `0` even if the numbers in those cells are greater than 0.

The formula is

```
=K2*J2
```

The values I see in those cells are:
K2 = 16.32
J2 = 380

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't know what is the problem, but here are some tips: Check the format of all the three cells for strange settings, set the formats to "general". Try to multiply both cells with 1.

Comment: In addition to the suggestion by @MátéJuhász set the formats to Number. Most likely, at least one of the cells is formatted as text. For math operations, Excel treats text as `0`.

Comment: @EngineerToast, even if one or more values are text, the multiplication will coerce them into numbers and the result will not be a 0.

Comment: @YSilber, can you share the file on a file sharing site?

Comment: Try placing the same formula `=K2*J2` in a different cell, preferably with no formatting.

Comment: Try `=value(J2)*value(K2)` . If this is correct, then one or both of the values is text. BTW, by default, text is left aligned; true numbers are right aligned.

Comment: Make sure your system work with *decimal point* instead of *comma*. Maybe 16.32 should be *16,32*.

Comment: @EngineerToast, for me it's working even when both cell has Text format, and if for your computer Decimal is Comma and Comma is Decimal then Formula should return #Value error not ZERO. Better you share the File on cloud or on Drop Box to be examined!!

Comment: @EngineerToast,, try this once,, In any blank cell, type `1`, Make sure the cell in which you typed `1` is formatted as a `Number`,
Select the cell with the `1` and `Copy,,`
Select the cells with the values you want to convert to Numbers,, Choose `Paste Special`
Under `Operation`, click `Multiply` and then click `OK`

Comment: Hi @Y Silber,, better share the Workbook on cloud or through Drop Box and let me and others to examine the data on sheet !

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this too and the problem was that I was referring to the wrong cell. When you merge cells, a single cell can consist of multiple rows or columns. Make sure to use the far left column or the top row when you reference a merged cell.

Comment: Underrated comment here! This part isn't documented well.

Answer (score 1):

Also check to see if you are creating a circular calculation.  If Excel is already warning you of a circular calculation in another part of your spreadsheet, it won't directly warn you if you create another circular calculation.  It may just give you a 0 result instead.